# executing sparql query on all the result of another sparql query

Tags: sparql

Suppose I have a list of names returned from a sparql query. And another query that uses a name from this list and returns something else. How can I execute this query on all names in the list returned by the other query? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You use a subquery.  E.g.,

```sql
select ?country ?capital {
  { select ?country {
      #-- criteria for selecting country
  }

  ?country :hasCapital ?country
}
```

Note that in trivial cases, you wouldn't need a separate subquery, you could just do:

```sql
select ?country ?capital {
  #-- criteria for selecting country
  ?country :hasCapital ?country
}
```

Comment: @jango If this worked, do consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: What if the program I am working with does not support subquery?